# Sequelize chain find with belongsTo

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have three models, Discussion, User and Message, where:

```
Message.belongsTo(models.Discussion, {as: 'discussion'})
Discussion.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: models.UserDiscussion})
```

I would like to get all messages concerning a specific user. From the user, I can easily get all the discussions with `user.getDiscussions()`.
But then I don't know how to find the messages in a single request. Once I have the discussions array, I can call find

```
models.Message.findAll({where: {discussionId: discussions[i].id}})
```

for every discussion in the array, but this is asynchronous and I don't know how to chain them, to return only the messages.

Is there no getter with a belongsTo relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you're searching for your user, you should be able to do something like:

```
Discusson.findAll({ 
    // where query 
    },
    {
       include: [Message]
    })
    .then(function(user) {

    });
```